# How kubelet sync events to apiserver?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, kubernetes-apiserver

Recently I research how kubelet sync events to apiserver but I can't find where the code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of kubelet is available [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/pkg/kubelet).

> Kubelet can obtain Pod configurations required by the local node in multiple ways. The most important way is **Apiserver**. Kubelet can also obtain the Pod configurations by specifying the file directory or accessing the specified HTTP port.

On the startup of Kubelet, a `PodConfig` object is created.
Code [kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/config/config.go#L58](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/config/config.go#L58):

```
type PodConfig struct {
    pods *podStorage
    mux  *config.Mux

    // the channel of denormalized changes passed to listeners
    updates chan kubetypes.PodUpdate
    ...
}
```

> `PodConfig` is essentially a multiplexer of Pod configurations. The built-in `mux` can listen on the sources of various Pod configurations (including apiserver, file, and http), and periodically synchronize the Pod configuration status of the sources.

Code [kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/types/pod_update.go#L80](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/types/pod_update.go#L80):

```
type PodUpdate struct {
    Pods   []*v1.Pod
    Op     PodOperation
    Source string
}
```

The `Op` defines the Pod change type. For example those can be values like `ADD` or `REMOVE`. In the end all types of `PodUpdate` will be injected to `updates` of `podConfig`. So there is only a need to listen to `update` channel to get Pod configuration updates of the local node.

Once Kubelet startup is complete, the `syncLoop` function is executed.
Code [kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go#L180](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go#L1806):

```
// syncLoop is the main loop for processing changes. It watches for changes from
// three channels (file, apiserver, and http) and creates a union of them. For
// any new change seen, will run a sync against desired state and running state. If
// no changes are seen to the configuration, will synchronize the last known desired
// state every sync-frequency seconds. Never returns.
    func (kl *Kubelet) syncLoop(updates <-chan kubetypes.PodUpdate, handler SyncHandler) {
        ...
        for {
            ...
            if !kl.syncLoopIteration(updates, handler, syncTicker.C, housekeepingTicker.C, plegCh) {
                break
            }
            ...
    }
```

The whole process is explained in detail in the following article: [Understanding the Kubelet Core Execution Frame](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-the-kubelet-core-execution-frame).

Comment: This is how kubelet get config from apiserver. But how kubelet record message like OOM to apiserver?

Comment: Maybe this will help you understand how does the communication work, [Master-Node communication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/master-node-communication/)